# How can I formally multiply two polynomials from different rings?

Tags: python, sage

Suppose I take a polynomial from $R[x]$ say $x^2+5x$ and another polynomial from $R[y]$ say $y^3$. I want to formally multiply them and print $x^2y^3 +5xy^3$ as the output.

How can I do that?

Note: K is finite field of size 4 in 'a'

My efforts:

```
R_1=PolynomialRing(K,['z%s'%p for p in range(1,3)])
R_2=PolynomialRing(K,['x%s'%p for p in range(1,3)])

pp=R_1.random_element()
(a + 1)*z1^2 + (a)*z1*z2 + (a + 1)*z2 + (a)

qq=R_2.random_element()
x1*x2 + (a + 1)*x2^2 + x1 + 1
```

When I do `pp*qq` I get the following output

```
unsupported operand parent(s) for *: 'Multivariate Polynomial Ring in z1, z2 over Finite Field in a of size 2^2' and 'Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x1, x2 over Finite Field in a of size 2^2'
```

Comment: `pp` and `qq` in your case belong to 2 different rings. Don't you want them both to be from the same ring, so they can be multiplied ?

Comment: Also asked (and answered) as [Ask Sage question 55351](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/55351).